# Is there a standard package to create a table like this?

Tags: tables

Is there a fast and efficient way to create a table with a vertical arrow like this?

[image]

A suitable reference or a snippet of LaTeX code would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make sure that all images are uploaded using the official stackexchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: CTRL+G). This ensures that all images are always accessible and do not expire. As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: I am not a TeXpert (yet) but have a feeling it should be possible using Tikz package, where you can reference the start and end of the arrow by points. Text out of table is no problem as you specify the boundaries between columns when you start the tabular environment.

Comment: There is no ‘standard’ package, but I will suggest that you try the [Tabu](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/tabu)-package. Then you have a chance to have the vertical rules lining up with the horizontal even if you add some space between the table text and the table rules.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an outline answer using `tabularx` and `tikz`.

I apologise for (a) Not filling in all the text and (b) not tuning the horizontal fit and spacing.

[image: Image of result]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\vstrut}[1]{\rule{0pt}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\node [text width=7cm] (tb) {%
\begin{tabularx}{7cm}{|p{2.5cm}|X|}
    \hline
    Extraordinary uncertainty
    & Fundamental Research\newline
      Fundamental invention\\
    \hline
    \vstrut{2cm} & \\
    \hline
    \vstrut{2cm} & \\
    \hline
    \vstrut{2cm} & \\
    \hline
    \vstrut{2cm} & \\
    \hline
    \vstrut{2cm} & \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
} ;
\node [
    anchor=north west,
    right=of tb.55,
    text width=2cm] (br) {Basic\\Research};
\node [
    anchor=west,
    right=of tb.0,
    text width=2cm] (dv) {Development};
\node [
    anchor=south west,
    right=of tb.305,
    text width=2cm] (ar) {Applied\\Research};
\node [coordinate,right=of br.north east] (x1) {};
\node [coordinate,right=of ar.south east] (x2) {};
\draw [<->] (x1) to (x2);
\node [right=2cm of br,text width=2cm] {\bfseries\itshape Radical\\Innovation};
\node [right=2cm of ar,text width=2cm] {\bfseries\itshape Incremental\\Innovation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I hope that helps. TikZ is very good, but tends to be "wordy".

Answer (score 14):

It's possible to combine the `multirow` package and tikz. I think it's more easy to place the text like Title A and B. I use tikz only for the arrows.

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
 \usepackage{tikz,multirow}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | p{5cm} |l l}
 \cline{1-3}  
   Day & Max Temp & Summary &\multirow{2}{*}{Title A} &
    \multirow{2}{*}{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \coordinate (a);\hspace*{2ex}\textbf{Top}} \\ 
   \cline{1-3}
   Monday & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.  However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures.&  & \\ \cline{1-3}
   Tuesday & 19C & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, but rain reaching the far northwest.& &\\ 
   \cline{1-3}
   Wednesday & 21C & Rain will still linger for the morning. Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue throughout the evening.&
   \multirow{2}{*}[1em]{Title B} &  \multirow{2}{*}[-4em]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \coordinate (b);\hspace*{2ex}\textbf{Below}} \\
 \cline{1-3}
   \end{tabular} %
 \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw[<->] (a) --(b);
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will upvote as soon as I get enough rep points.

Comment: @TeXnician No problem for the upvote, I hope that this new approach is interesting for you or for other users.

Comment: @TeXnician: This answer is so much better than mine, in so many ways. I wouldn't be at all offended if you were to unaccept my answer and accept this one...